# Are there technical or code style reasons not to name your IIFE functions?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, iife

An *Immediately Invoked Function Expression* ([defined and explained here](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/)) is often written like...

`(function() { /* code */ })();`

From the article above, Ben Alman adds this comment:

> Adding an identifier to a function expression (thus creating a named function expression) can be extremely helpful when debugging.

There is a debugging advantage to naming your IIFE, like...

`(function myComponentIIFE(){ /* code */ })();`

If there is some advantage, then it seems that it should be common practice to name all of your otherwise-anonymous IIFEs. Is there a reason why IIFEs are usually anonymous? Are anonymous functions handled differently such that they have some advantage?

Comment: Do you plan on reusing the function?  Why leave a dangling name to a function that you won't use again and don't want others to be able to use?

Comment: Benefits are in code readability and readable stack traces. Try `(function outerComponentIIFE(){ (function innerComponentIIFE(){ shouldThrowError(); })(); })();` in the console compared to `(function(){ (function(){ shouldThrowError(); })(); })();`

Comment: Unless you don't have to support old IE<9, there's no difference between anonymous and named function expression. Additionally named function expression gets its name within the function where it can be used to recursion, and for example remove an event listener in the handler itself.

Comment: @Teemu Care to elaborate on "there's no difference between anonymous and named function expression" with a reference for an answer?

Comment: The only difference is that a named function creates a binding inside the function that references itself. There isn't any difference functionality-wise.

Answer (score 0):

`(function() { /* code */ })()` is shorter than `(function myComponentIIFE(){ /* code */ })()`, takes 2 less bytes in minified code and less time to think up and type.

Function name is *extremely helpful when debugging* only when it's debugged in unminified application with text log that cannot be linked to respective lines. In any other case it's rather useless.

In minified application it doesn't benefit debugging and becomes something like:

```
(function a(){ /* code */ })();
```

In browser console output stack trace entries can be dynamically navigated to actual code by clicking on them.

IIFEs have limited use in modern JavaScript. IIFEs were heavily used in ES5 to implement Module Pattern and/or provide a scope for a block of code. These uses are currently handled by ES6 block scopes and modules.

Most IIFEs that exist in the application will be generated automatically by the tools. Only a few of them are written by a developer. If it's known that IIFE benefits debugging or results in self-documenting code, then yes, it makes sense to give a function a name.

An example in modern JS is `async` IIFE that has its uses, for instance, as application entry point:

```
(async function main() {
  // ...
})()
.catch(console.error);
```